# MUX for different voltage levels

Tags: differential

I have a project which has two inputs. Based on what signal the user inputs, a MUX (or something else (not relay - it needs to me ultra small and very low power)) directs it to the appropriate pins of the MCU or to a conversion chip. The directing is configured by the user before connecting. The three choices of signals are:
-differential signal (two lines): +2.5 idle and 0V/5V (high). Signal must be unaltered through the switch.
-0V low, 12V high. (only one signal line)
-0V low, 7V high. (only one signal line)

I have 12V, 5V, 4.2V and 3.3V rails available in the project.
The 7V and 12V signals are conditioned and protected before entering the MCU.

How can I have only 2 inputs, then MUX such various signals? I can't divide any signals before MUX because of the differential signal. And most MUX seems to only accept signals lower than their VCC.

Answer (score 0):

Analog switches support all voltages between their power rails. So just connect the mux to the 12 V supply. If your control signals are not at 12 V, choose a mux that accepts lower voltages at its control pins.

You want a two-channel, 3:1 switch. In practice, there are more 4:1 switches. The common CD4052B has an on resistance of 150 Ω, which is probably too much for your differential signals. Use the search function of your merchant or manufacturer; you will probably end up with something like the TMUX6209.